# Swapping Array elements not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I am new to javascript , I am little confused with swapping.Actually my swapping function works it is not working in specific condition.

My data structure

```
let WholeSeq = [] //variable name for image content
```

[image: WholeSeq]

For Example:-
Working condition

```
let SwapThis = this.swapArrayElements([1,2,3],0,1) //Working
```

Not Working

```
 let SwapThis = this.swapArrayElements(WholeSeq[0].Sequence,0,1) // Not Working
```

My Swap Array Function

```
swapArrayElements(a, x, y){
        if (a.length === 1) return a;
        a.splice(y, 1, a.splice(x, 1, a[y])[0]);
        return a;
    }
```

Whole Simulated Algorithm

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import _ from 'lodash';
import lupus from 'lupus';

let newRandomPop = [];

let howManyMachines = 2;
let njobs = 6;


let time = [5,3,1,2,4,6];



class SA extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            njobs:njobs,
            time:time,
            howManyMachines:howManyMachines,
            bestValue:0
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.generatePopulation();
    }
    swapArrayElements(a, x, y){
        if (a.length === 1) return a;
        a.splice(y, 1, a.splice(x, 1, a[y])[0]);
        return a;
    }
    generateRandomeNumberPaticularSequence(maximum,minimum){
        return Math.round( Math.random() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum);
    }
    SwapThis(WholeSeq){

        let newSeq = [];

        console.log(WholeSeq[0].Sequence);



         //This Swaping is not working
        console.log(this.swapArrayElements(WholeSeq[0].Sequence,0,1))
    }

    takeDecision(bestValue){
        if(this.state.bestValue < bestValue){
            console.log('Negative Value')

        }else{
            this.setState({
                bestValue

            })
        }

    }

    AllotFitnessRate(newMachine){
        let NewMachineArrayWithFitnessRate = [];
        let TotalMaxValue = newMachine.reduce((sum,MaxValue) => {
            return sum + MaxValue.MaxValue
        },0);
        let AvgValue = TotalMaxValue/newMachine.length
        newMachine.forEach(data => {
            let newArrayWithFitness ={

                fitness:(data.MaxValue/AvgValue),
                MaxValue:data.MaxValue,
                MachineArr:data.MachineArr,
                Sequence:data.Sequence
            }
            NewMachineArrayWithFitnessRate.push(newArrayWithFitness)
        });
     this.takeDecision(NewMachineArrayWithFitnessRate[0].MaxValue)
     this.SwapThis(NewMachineArrayWithFitnessRate)
    }

    allortAllSequenceForTesting(allSequence){
        console.log('From Se',allSequence)
        const NewMachine = [];
        for(let i=0;i<allSequence.length;i++){
            let machines = Array(this.state.howManyMachines).fill().map((m, i) => {
                return {
                    id: i,
                    value: 0,
                    jobs: [],
                    name:"M"+(i+1)

                } });
            allSequence[i].forEach(job => {
                // console.log(allSequence[i])
                let minMachine = machines
                    .slice(1)
                    .reduce((res, cur) =>
                        res.value <= cur.value ? res : cur, machines[0]);
                minMachine.jobs.push(job);
                minMachine.value += job.timeToFinish;

            });
            let HigestValueArray = _.map(machines, function (o) {
                return o.value;
            });
            let subArrayMaxValue = _.max(HigestValueArray);
            // console.log("Befor",subArrayMaxValue);
            // console.log(machines);
            const ArrayShouldBePushed = {
                MaxValue:subArrayMaxValue,
                MachineArr:machines,
                Sequence:allSequence[i]
            }

            NewMachine.push(ArrayShouldBePushed);
        }

        let sortThis = _.sortBy(NewMachine,'MaxValue');
        // sortThis.map(data => {
        //
        //     console.log("===============",data.MaxValue)
        //     console.log(data.Sequence.map(data => {
        //         return data.jobId
        //     }))
        //    data.MachineArr.map(data => {
        //        console.log("Machine Name",data.name)
        //        data.jobs.map(data => {
        //
        //            console.log(data.jobId," ",data.timeToFinish)
        //
        //        })
        //    })
        //
        // })
        this.AllotFitnessRate(sortThis)
    }
    generatePopulation(){
        let allJobs =  Array(this.state.njobs).fill().map((m,i) => {
            return {
                jobId:"j"+(i+1),
                timeToFinish:this.state.time[i]
            }
        });
        for(let i =0;i<2;i++){
            let pushtoNewArray = _.shuffle(allJobs);
            newRandomPop.push(pushtoNewArray)

        }
        this.allortAllSequenceForTesting(newRandomPop);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                Hellp
            </div>
        )
    }
}

render(<SA/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

There will be lot of functions but the main function is

```
SwapThis(WholeSeq){
            let newSeq = [];

            console.log(WholeSeq[0].Sequence);

             //This Swaping is not working
            console.log(this.swapArrayElements(WholeSeq[0].Sequence,0,1))
        }
```

Comment: what is `WholeSeq[0].Sequence`?

Comment: WholeSeq is the array of object that variable value in the picture see that

Comment: and it is "not working" how? what do you expect and what you actually get?

Comment: I tried it. All worked fine for me

Comment: run it: https://jsfiddle.net/damienleroux/ypo31c4h/

Comment: @DamienLeroux It is Actually working for me too But I am trying to implement simulated algorithm in javasscript/React js It is not working inside the algorithm Or wait i will post whole algorithm

Comment: I suggest you to create a [React/JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/) to demonstrate your problem. Then share it with us. Please provide minimal code too: provide only code that can produce the bad behavior. Thx